# How to find the number of emails sent to a single domain within this entire year by creating SQL Query for salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I am using this below and it is not pulling the count into the data extension created once automation is complete. Only SubscriberKey and EmailAddress pulls in to the data extension, once automation is complete. Any Assistance?

`[SELECT count() AS TotalSent, SubscriberKey as EmailAddress, SubscriberKey FROM _Sent WHERE Domain LIKE '%site-dev.com%' AND EventDate between '2018-01-01' and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP GROUP BY SubscriberKey HAVING COUNT() > 0]`

Answer (score 0):

To find the number of emails sent to a certain domain, you could look at the email log portion of Salesforce under the quick find and pull a report of email. Then filter for the emails with the specific domain name.